# Using whenever gem to schedule a cron job

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, whenever

I'm testing whenever to figure out how to use it and am running into trouble even after reading the Github documentation.

I simply want to update the attributes of my model like this (config/schedule.rb)

set :output "/log/today.log"

```
every 10.seconds do
  runner "Example.update_all(sample: Time.now)"
end
```

I am neither seeing a log file nor seeing the model attributes updated.

Is there anything I am not doing correctly?

Comment: Have you deployed crontab job ? Try run `whenever -w`. Also you could try `crontab -l`, it should contain your line from schedule.rb

Comment: Did this earlier today, and the output is below. Not sure why it's choosing to do this in production only? I'm testing this locally so that could explain why it's not firing.

Comment: `whenever --help` has options to set environment, check it out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to add your cron job in the cron tab.
If you do not want to add because you are just testing it, you can try the code given below(which i did for my rails application).

`cd /home/your_home/your_project && script/your_script -e <environment> "method_call"`

In your case:

`environment = development`
`method_call = Example.update_all(sample: Time.now)`

It might help you.

Comment: This is what the output of my crontab -l is: # Begin Whenever generated tasks for: /Users/bhander/Dropbox/workspace/rails_projects/chores/config/schedule.rb
* * * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /home/your_home/you_project && script/rails runner -e production '\''Example.update_all(sample: Time.now)'\'' >> /log/today.log 2>&1'

Comment: I suspect because it's in the production environment I'm not seeing the update on my localhost. Is this easily changed?